# How to redirect to a new VF page with command link and outputlink?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I have a list of Assets

```
Name:  column 2:  etc

A1      C1        b1
A2      c2        b2
```

When I click on A1, I call  action="{! assetClicked}" within  to do some logic, but I cannot redirect it to another Visual Force Page
If I use  I can link to another VF page, but cannot do  action="{! assetClicked}"

Is there a way to combine them together or some other way around?

Page Code:

```
<apex:form >
  <apex:commandLink action="{! assetClicked}" value="{!wn.name}" id="theCommandLink"> 
    <apex:param value="{!wn.name}" name="id" assignTo="{!selectedAsset}" ></apex:param>
    <apex:outputLink value="/{!wn.id}" id="eventlink">{!wn.name}</apex:outputLink>
  </apex:commandLink> 
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't indicate how to retrieve the parameter in the desintation Visualforce page controller. I found this in a different forum:

```
// Assuming the parameter is 'id' after redirecting to page2 you can retrieve the paramter thus
public customcontrollerpage2() {
    String ID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You would need to use the [PageReference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_pages_pagereference.htm) class.

Here's a modified example from the documentation:

```
// selected asset property
public string selectedAsset {get;set;}

public PageReference assetClicked() 
{
    // Your code here

    PageReference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/PageName'); 

    // pass the selected asset ID to the new page
    redirect.getParameters().put('id',selectedAsset); 
    redirect.setRedirect(true); 

    return redirect;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `Page.PageName;` instead of `new PageReference('/apex/PageName');` as described [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_controller_navigation_methods.htm).

Answer (score 0):

In button method add something like this at the end of the method:

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/YOUR_PAGE_NAME');

return pr;
```

Comment: Thanks, I do not have a button, I am clicking on a link (Asset name) in a column.

 </apex:outputLink> works, but it cannot call a method in controller